# Filter dictionaries within a series by value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
                             scope
0  {'range': 2, 'category': '234'}
1  {'range': 1, 'category': '222'}
```

I would like to filter rows by condition "range==1".How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `pd.Series.apply` to create a Boolean indexer.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'scope': [{'range': 2, 'category': '234'},
                             {'range': 1, 'category': '222'}]})

res = df[df['scope'].apply(lambda x: x['range'] == 1)]

#                              scope
# 1  {'range': 1, 'category': '222'}
```

Comment: Exactly what I want.Thank you:)

Comment: I find that if df is a empty dataframe,it returns a dataframe without column names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
import pandas as pd
filter = pd.DataFrame({"scope": [i for i in df["scope"] if i["range"] == 1]})
```

Comment: It works in this condition.However,if i have serveral columns,it's inconvenient.